# Using Spark to write a parquet file to s3 over s3a is very slow

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm trying to write a `parquet` file out to `Amazon S3` using `Spark 1.6.1`.  The small `parquet` that I'm generating is `~2GB` once written so it's not that much data.  I'm trying to prove `Spark` out as a platform that I can use.

Basically what I'm going is setting up a `star schema` with `dataframes`, then I'm going to write those tables out to parquet.  The data comes in from csv files provided by a vendor and I'm using Spark as an `ETL` platform.  I currently have a 3 node cluster in `ec2(r3.2xlarge)` So `120GB` of memory on the executors and 16 cores total.

The input files total about 22GB and I'm extracting about 2GB of that data for now.  Eventually this will be many terabytes when I start loading the full dataset.

Here is my spark/scala `pseudocode`:

```
  def loadStage(): Unit = {
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.buffer.dir", "/tmp/tempData")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class","org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet","false")
    var sqlCtx = new SQLContext(sc)


    val DataFile = sc.textFile("s3a://my-bucket/archive/*/file*.gz")

    //Setup header table/df
    val header_rec = DataFile.map(_.split("\\|")).filter(x=> x(0) == "1")
    val headerSchemaDef = "market_no,rel_date,field1, field2, field3....."
    val headerSchema = StructType(headerSchemaDef.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType,false)))
    val headerRecords = header_rec.map(p => Row(p(3), p(8), p(1), p(2), p(4), p(5), p(6) ))
    val header = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(headerRecords, headerSchema)
    header.registerTempTable("header")
    sqlCtx.cacheTable("header")


    //Setup fact table/df
    val fact_recs = DataFile.map(_.split("\\|")).filter(x=> x(0) == "2")
    val factSchemaDef = "market_no,rel_date,field1, field2, field3....."
    val factSchema = StructType(factSchemaDef.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType,false)))
    val records = fact_recs.map(p => Row(p(11), p(12), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), p(6), p(7), p(8), p(9), p(10)))
    val df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(records, factSchema)
    df.registerTempTable("fact")

    val results = sqlCtx.sql("select fact.* from header inner join fact on fact.market_no = header.market_no and fact.rel_date = header.rel_date")


    println(results.count())



    results.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("s3a://my-bucket/a/joined_data.parquet")


  }
```

The count takes about 2 minutes for 465884512 rows.  The write to parquet takes **38 minutes**

I understand that the `coalesce` does a shuffle to the driver which does the write....  but the amount of time it's taking is making me think I'm doing something seriously wrong.  Without the `coalesce`, this still takes 15 minutes, which IMO is still too long and gives me a ton of small `parquet` files.  I'd like to have one large file per day of data that I'll have.  I have code to do the *partitioning by a field value* as well, and it is just as slow.  I've also tried to output this to `csv` and that takes ~1 hour.

Also, I'm not really setting run time props when I'm submitting my job. My console stats for one job are:

- Alive Workers: 2
- Cores in use: 16 Total, 16 Used
- Memory in use: 117.5 GB Total, 107.5 GB Used
- Applications: 1 Running, 5 Completed
- Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
- Status: ALIVE

Comment: a coalesce does not shuffle to the driver it shuffles between executors but this is irrelevant to the problem you are seeing. Are you using EMR? if so use s3:// and not s3a://. either way on Spark 1.6 you should use Direct OutputCommitter like @David says. Another possible improvement is to set parquet.enable.summary-metadata to false

Comment: Does using Alluxio in front of S3 speed it up at all?

Answer (score 19):

Spark defaults cause a large amount of (probably) unnecessary overhead during I/O operations, especially when writing to S3. [This article](https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/the-bleeding-edge-spark-parquet-and-s3/) discusses this more thoroughly, but there are 2 settings you'll want to consider changing.

- <s>Using the DirectParquetOutputCommitter. By default, Spark will save all of the data to a temporary folder then move those files afterwards. Using the DirectParquetOutputCommitter will save time by directly writting to the S3 output path</s>

  - [No longer available in Spark 2.0+](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10063)

    - As stated in the jira ticket, the current solution is to

      > 1. Switch your code to using s3a and Hadoop 2.7.2+ ; it's better all round, gets better in Hadoop 2.8, and is the basis for s3guard
      > 2. Use the Hadoop FileOutputCommitter and set mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version to 2

  -Schema merging is turned off by default as of [Spark 1.5](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging)  <s>Turn off Schema Merging. If schema merging is on, the driver node will scan all of the files to ensure a consistent schema. This is especially costly because it is not a distributed operation. Make sure this is turned off by doing</s>

  `val file = sqx.read.option("mergeSchema", "false").parquet(path)`

Comment: as of Spark 2.0 DirectParquetOutputCommitter is no longer available. see [SPARK-10063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10063) for new solution

Comment: @TalJoffe have you tried their solution? If so, how did it work? And can you answer with how?

Comment: I did try it works pretty well. I did a small test on a 30g folder and performance was pretty much the same

Comment: If performance was pretty much the same, doesn't that mean it's not really a valid solution?

Comment: @zzztimbo I took his comment to mean the workaround that was pointed out performed as well as the deprecated DirectParquetOutputCommitter (and thus better than the out of the box way of writing parquet files). But, I have yet to try it.

Comment: Merge schema is also false by default since 1.5.0 http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging

Answer (score 4):

The direct output committer is gone from the spark codebase; you are to write your own/resurrect the deleted code in your own JAR. IF you do so, turn speculation off in your work, and know that other failures can cause problems too, where problem is "invalid data".

On a brighter note, Hadoop 2.8 is going to add some S3A speedups specifically for reading optimised binary formats (ORC, Parquet) off S3; see [HADOOP-11694](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11694) for details. And some people are working on using Amazon Dynamo for the consistent metadata store which should be able to do a robust O(1) commit at the end of work.

Answer (score 2):

One of the immediate approaches to speed up Spark writes to S3 is to use the [EMRFS S3-optimized Committer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3-optimized-committer.html) .

However, if you use s3a this committer [cannot be used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-committer-reqs.html):

> When the EMRFS S3-optimized Committer is Not Used
>
> The committer is not used under the following circumstances:
>
> ```
> When writing to HDFS
>
> -> When using the S3A file system
>
> When using an output format other than Parquet, such as ORC or text
>
> When using MapReduce or Spark's RDD API
> ```

I've tested this difference on AWS EMR 5.26, and using s3:// was 15%-30% faster than s3a:// (but still slow).

The fastest way I've managed to accomplish such a copy/write was to write Parquet to a local HDFS and then use [s3distcp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) to copy to S3; in one specific scenario (a few hundreds of small files) this was 5x times faster than writing a DataFrame to Parquet directly to S3.

Comment: +1 to the idea of first writing to HDFS, then moving those files up to s3 afterwards (although I'm using gnu parallel + the aws cli command instead of s3distcp).  Definitely depends on your data though, this isn't a solution for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. Additional from what the rest said, here is a complete explanation from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/improve-apache-spark-write-performance-on-apache-parquet-formats-with-the-emrfs-s3-optimized-committer/

During my experiment just changing to FileOutCommiter v2(from v1) improved the write 3-4x.

```
self.sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
```